# Supposed Directory resolves to a File object ( TIZEN Filesystem API )

Tags: javascript, web-applications, filesystems, tizen

I am developing a web application for SAMSUNG displays using the TIZEN architecture. I have implemented the Filesystem API, however now I am stuck at a problem I do not understand and the documntaton is.. let's say sparse.

Currently the application creates a data folder in wgt-private, so that I have wgt-private/data/. However when attempting to resolve this path I receive a File object, which prevents me from creating a file, since a File object does not offer a createFile() method as a Directory object does - obviously.

Code to create the directory. Deferred functionality as well as callbacks are implemented, which is redundant, but this can be ignored for this thread. Essential is mostly the first success-callback of the TIZEN resolve function, that retrieves an object from Filesystem API:

```
tizen.filesystem.resolve(
            homePath,
            function ( obj ) {
                var exceptionThrown = false; 
                try {
                    var newDir = obj.createDirectory( path );
                } catch ( e ){
                    Logger.debug("[DIRECTORY] Could not create directory:");
                    Logger.debug( e.message );
                    Logger.debug( e );
                    exceptionThrown = true;
                }

                // check if an exception occurred
                if ( exceptionThrown == true ) {
                    dfd.resolve();
                    if ( failure_cb != null && typeof( failure_cb ) === 'function' ){
                        failure_cb( path );
                    }
                } else {
                    dfd.resolve();
                    if ( success_cb != null && typeof( success_cb ) === 'function' ){
                        self.exists( path, success_cb, failure_cb )
                    }
                }
            },
            function ( e ) {
                Logger.debug("[DIRECTORY] Attempted to create directory, but could not resolve location due to error:");
                dfd.resolve();
                Logger.debug( e );
                if ( failure_cb != null && typeof( failure_cb ) === 'function' ){
                    failure_cb( path );
                }
            }
    );
```

This is the call to create a file by retrieving a Directory object and calling createFile. Again there are Deferred resolves and callbacks that can be ignored. Essential is that resolving wgt-private/data should give me a Directory object (I specifically checked that the success callback is called for creating /data and it is created using createDirectory) but instead I receive a File object:

```
tizen.filesystem.resolve(
            'wgt-private/data',
            function ( obj ) {
                try {
                    Logger.debug( obj );
                    obj.createFile( filename ); // create file at location
                } catch ( e ) {
                    Logger.debug("[FILE] Exception caught while attempting to create file " + path);
                    Logger.debug( e.message );
                    Logger.debug( e );
                }
                self.exists( path, success_cb, failure_cb ); // if exists --> success
            },
            function ( err ) {
                Logger.error("[FILE] Could not create file!");
                Logger.error( err );

                // couldn't create file - failure-callback
                if ( failure_cb != null && typeof( failure_cb ) === 'function' ){
                    failure_cb( path );
                }
            },
            "rw"
        );
```

I do not understand this behavior. I can resolve just wgt-private in this same fashion just fine, but resolving a subpath tells me I am resolving a File. Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Basically,

    obj.createDirectory()

creates a file. Those are even listed when calling 

    obj.listFiles()

on a Directory object. How is this possible?

Comment: So I tested this again manually using the console and created a directory /cool by hand. This directory is now listed in listFiles as well, which doesn't make any sense to me. How am I supposed to create files in a subdirectory then, if I cannot resolve a directory object other than the virtual root?...

Comment: As the documentation says, listFiles will return File objects (which apparently directories are as well within TIZEN). However this doesn't change the fact, that TIZEN is considering the directories I resolve to be files apparently, as it tells me:

    IOError: File object which call this method is not directory

Answer (score 0):

When you are resolving location using tizen.filesystem.resolve() function,
you are resolving the location from Tizen FileSystem.

'wgt-private' is not an actual path, rather it denotes a virtual path. For example like 'file://opt/usr/abcd.yourapp'. When you feed the 'wgt-private' parameter to tizen.filesystem.resolve() it resolves for you the private folder in which the widget stores its information.

Once you have resolved the private folder from Tizen Filesystem, then you have to resolve the private folder for data folder.

```
tizen.filesystem.resolve('wgt-private', function(obj)
{
   file = obj.resolve('data');
}, function(e)
{
   console.log("Error" + e.message);
}, "rw");
```

Reference: [resolve()](https://developer.tizen.org/development/api-references/web-application?redirect=/dev-guide/latest/org.tizen.web.apireference/html/device_api/wearable/tizen/filesystem.html#FileSystemManager::resolve)

Comment: Hey there, I am aware of wgt-private being a virtual root and the actual path being the URI. The problem was, I was under the impression of being given a File object with isFile = true from resolving wgt-private, but unbeknownst to me another call happened at the same time in a streaming method, where the resolved path was indeed wrong. In conclusion what I posted works just fine, the error was elsewhere in the code. Case closed.